# fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: docker, opencv, java-17

I created the following docker image containing a spring boot application that performs opencv and tesseract operations:

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine


RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache tesseract-ocr opencv gcompat

COPY myapp-1.0.0.jar myapp-1.0.0.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/myapp-1.0.0.jar"]
```

When i try to run it on a linux machine (2 differnt vms or google.cloud), it starts, other endpoints work but when i call the endpoint that starts the opencv operations, i get the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000001e1766, pid=1, tid=124
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (17.0+14) (build 17-ea+14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (17-ea+14, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000001e1766
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e %P %I %h" (or dumping to //core.1)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid1.log
[thread 125 also had an error][thread 127 also had an error][thread 128 also had an error]
```

Can anybody help me to analyze that? I understand its a native C issue. Probably opencv or a dependency? But Why?
I think it starts with the following opencv function:

`Mat map = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(byteArray), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);`

complete error log [here](https://files.fm/down.php?i=c6zwn2zku)

Comment: Using the package distributor OpenCV packages can lead to a variety of problems due to being unable to control the compilation flags. This could mean for example that OpenCV tries to access the GPU (non existing in Docker) or other hardware features unavailable to it. I suggest that you try compiling manually OpenCV in Docker. This question I made a couple months ago could help you out in figuring how to install OpenCV in Docker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592138/opencv-docker-multistage-build-cannot-install-prebuilt-source

Comment: I tried to built it too. I also tried to take that image as base. https://github.com/akapril/alpine-opencv-java

Comment: Have you tried to run OpenCV with Java outside Docker? in a local environment with a local JDK?

Comment: Thank you @marc, i solved my issue by building it localy with ubuntu.